# How can I login to another website and maintain the session in the background so if the user accesses that website they are logged in already

Tags: php, curl, authentication, active-directory, single-sign-on

I am trying to create a portal such that users use SSO to access all services in the company I work for.

My goal is for the users to log in to my portal, then they will be automatically logged in to all the websites of our company and they will only need to click the icon of the website to access it without the need to enter their credentials every time, we are using Active Directory for authentication in all these websites.

I inspected the login form for each website and got the URLs of the login scripts along with the variable names of the username and password fields, then I tried to send POST requests to those scripts using cURL in PHP with the credentials in the "CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS" option.

```
    $cookie_file_path = getcwd() . '/cookie.txt';
    $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $ch = curl_init(); 

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com/login.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file_path);

    $loginpage_html = curl_exec ($ch);

    curl_close ($ch);

    $CREDENTIALS = "username=test&password=test";  

    $ch = curl_init(); 


    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'http://example.com/login.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$CREDENTIALS); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://example.com/login.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  $cookie_file_path);

    $logon_result = curl_exec ($ch);
    echo $logon_result;
```

Current output:
Users are automatically logged in to all the websites when they login to my portal, but when trying to navigate it looks like they haven't logged in in the first place as if the session is destroyed even though it first shows that you're logged in.

Expected output:
Users are automatically logged in to all the websites when they login to my portal and can access those websites as if they are normally logged in.

And as a beginner, I want to ask is this actually a good way to achieve SSO in PHP and Active Directory or is there a better way to do this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is failing to log in users because the session cookies aren't being saved to the clients web browser. For security reasons your site won't be able to create a cookie for another website. Since your users don't have the session cookie for the target site they will be treated like a new user.

A more common way to achieve a single sign experience would be to use SAML. Since you mentioned your company used Active Directory you can use ADFS as the Identity Provider. Some of your enterprise applications may already support SAML authentication.